# Passing components state to query variables inside react-apollo's compose

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

The following React component works correctly, I'm able to query a GraphQL endpoint using Apollo-React. In this specific case I'm using an Apollo-React's `compose` function, to add several queries in the same component.
I would like to inject dynamically, in the HOC `variables` field, the userId.
Is there a way to do it ? Because simply calling the function `getUser()`  doesn't seems to works, I get only a promise.

```
  class AllCardsScreen extends Component {

    state = {
      query: '',
      userCardsById: [],
      userId:'',
      loading: false,
    };

    getUser = async () => {
    await Auth.currentUserInfo()
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ userId: data.attributes.sub});
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`));
    };

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.userCardsList}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }


 export default compose(

  graphql(ListCards, {
    options: (props) => ({
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
      variables: { userId : '18e946df-d3de-49a8-98b3-8b6d74dfd652'}
    }),        
    props: (props) => ({
         userCardsList: props.data.userCardsList ? props.data.userCardsList.userCards : [],

    }),
  })

  )(AllCardsScreen);
```

EDIT:
This is the final working version based also on Daniel suggestion (Thx Daniel), with an API asyncronous call injected inside the HOC Apollo-graphQl enhancer. I had to call the `data.props.refetch()` function to update the `variables` value.

```
 class AuthWrapper extends React.Component {

    state = {
      userId: null,
    }

    async componentDidMount () {
      const data = await Auth.currentUserInfo()
      this.setState({ userId: data.attributes.sub})
    }

    render () {
      return this.state.userId
        ? <AllCardsScreen {...this.state} {...this.props}/>
        : null
    }
  }


class AllCardsScreen extends Component {

    state = {
      query: '',
      userCardsById: [],
      userId:'',
      loading: false,
    };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dataRefetch(this.props.userId)
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.userCardsList}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }


 export default compose(

  graphql(ListCards, {
    options: (props) => ({
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
      variables: { userId : ''}
    }),        
    props: (props) => ({
    userCardsList: props.data.userCardsList ? props.data.userCardsList.userCards : [],
    dataRefetch: (userId) => {
        props.data.refetch({userId})
       },
    }),
  })

  )(AllCardsScreen);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `graphql` HOC only uses props -- since it's effectively just wrapping the component it's passed, it won't have access to that component's state. There's also not a way to fetch data asynchronously inside the HOC's configuration.

The simplest solution is to just lift the state into either an existing parent component, or a new component that would wrap your existing one. For example:

```
class WrapperComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    userId: null,
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    const data = await Auth.currentUserInfo()
    this.setState({ userId: data.attributes.sub})
  }

  render () {
    // May want to render nothing or a loading indicator if userId is null
    return <AllCardsScreen userId={this.state.userId} {...otherProps} />
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create your own HOC to encapsulate the same logic:

```
function authHOC(WrappedComponent) {
  return class AuthWrapper extends React.Component {
    state = {
      userId: null,
    }

    async componentDidMount () {
      const data = await Auth.currentUserInfo()
      this.setState({ userId: data.attributes.sub})
    }

    render () {
      return this.state.userId
        ? <WrappedComponent {...this.props} userId={this.state.userId} />
        : null
    }
  }
}
```